# Redirect server traffic if web application fails

Tags: windows, iis, load-balancing

I have 3 web servers and a load balancer in front of them and these servers pointing to 1 domain. Lets say one of web app on the server throws status code except http 200(for example website gives 503 error.). How can I redirect server traffic to the other servers? Can I do it via Load balancer and IIS? If yes how? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault and thanks for asking the question.  Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that' s a common feature for a load-balancer.

I don't know which load balancer you are using, but you should be able to configure a **health check**: the load balancer will periodically check the health of the service (HTTP in your case) to determine if a server can actually process incoming requests or if it should be temporarily removed from the pool.

Comment: I dont know the software but they said we have F5 Load balancer. Can you give me a link that shows the way if you have it?

Comment: @godzkaya F5, of course they can do that! You can do [passive monitoring](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K7440) too(F5 can monitor responses and detect if the server is down without polling). More links: [F5 doc](https://techdocs.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-implementations-11-5-1/31.html)/[F5 Support K13622](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13622) [F5 Sup. K12531](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K12531) [F5 Sup. K2167](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K2167) [Health check,HTTP Errors](https://shaun.net/notes/f5-big-ip-health-checks-and-http-errors/)

Comment: @godzkaya additionally, your F5 admin should be able to do that for you or help you with this task.